# Accessing a variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript

I know this question sounds dumb. But I actually need help on this.

I have a local variable. I want to access that variable in a javascript function.

I know 2 ways to do it.

1st way is to pass it as an argument to the function.

The next way is to set the local variable to a global variable and access the global variable in the function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function func1(j)
        {
            alert(j);
        }

        function func2()
        {

            alert(globali2);
        }

        function test()
        {
            var i1 = 10;
            // First way. Passing argument to function
            func1(i1);

            // Second way. Using global variable.
            var i2 = 22;
            globali2 = i2;
            func2();
        }

        test();

    </script>
```

Is there any other way to access the variable inside a function.

Thanks,
Paul

Update:

I want to access a variable defined in 1st function from 2nd function. I will not be able to change the function signature of the 2nd function. The only solution I have right now is to use global variables. I just wish there is another way than using global variables.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: A global variable seems ok if both functions need access to that variable. You'd want to encapsulate your whole code in a IIFE to avoid leaking though. Check here http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Can you point where exactly you have the problem??

Comment: I want to access a variable defined in 1st function from 2nd function. I will not be able to change the function signature of the 2nd function. The only solution I have right now is to use global variables. I just wish there is another way than using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a very important design pattern which solves your problem: [namespacing](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/). It provides a way to handle variables needed in many different functions without handing them over as parameter each time and also avoiding global variables. This way your script produces a "minimal footprint" by only creating one member in the global space - your namespace. jQuery is the most prominent example which uses this design-pattern.

Javascript has a very powerful functions ([first-class member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)). This means for example that you can nest them:

```
// this is your namespace - it is the only point of access to your script
// no variable will leak out of it's scope
var yourNamespace = (function(){

    // these variables are local, but can be accessed
    // within every function of your namespace
    var pseudoglobal1 = ["foo","bar"],
        pseudoglobal2 = "123";

        function func1(){
            alert(pseudoglobal1 );
        }
        /*additional functions you need*/

        // functions you want to make public are returned here
        // IMPORTANT: the { must not be on a newline!
        return {
            publicName : func1
        }
})();
```

This way you avoid nasty global variables but nonetheless use your important variables in all of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

A 3rd way, very simple way:
You can define your function inside the same scope as the local variable. For ex if you define a function

```
func3() {
   alert(i1);
}
```

inside the function test(), this function will be able to return i1 !

See the code below:

```
function test()
{
   var i1 = 10;
   // First way. Passing argument to function
   func3()
   {
      alert(i1);
   }
   func3(); // this will alert i1
}
```

EDIT (remove some content):
*This is named "closure" (the inner functions have access to the variables of the outer functions) and it's a very interesting concept of Javascript !*

Comment: Thanks, but the functions might not be same scope in my case.

Comment: what you describe is *not* a closure. A closure is created when an inner function exists beyond the return of it's enclosing functions.

Comment: True, my bad. Closure would be returning this function for uses out of the enclosing scope.

Comment: @PaulNibin any additional comments on Ricola's or my answer?